# Why did God tell Laban to be careful to speak to Jacob neither good nor bad? (Genesis 31:24)

Tags: genesis, jacob, dream

Jacob fled from Laban. Laban then pursues Jacob; however, God speaks to Laban in a dream.

We read in Genesis 31:24 NKJV

> <sup>**24**</sup> But God had come to Laban the Syrian in a dream by
> night, and said to him, “**Be careful that you speak to Jacob neither
> good nor bad.**”

**Is there a reason that God tells Laban to be careful to speak neither good nor bad?** Also, as a secondary question, by "speak to Jacob neither good nor bad", does that mean about Jacob's character?

Answer (score 7):

This quintessentially Hebrew expression, to "speak neither good nor bad" occurs in another story of the rising antipathy between Absolom and Amnon after the latter raped their sister:

> 2 Sam 13:22 - And Absalom spoke to his brother Amnon **neither good nor
> bad**. For Absalom hated Amnon, because he had forced his sister Tamar.

There is also an instance in Gen 24:50 concerning the wife for Isaac:

> Gen 24:50 - Then Laban and Bethuel answered and said, “The thing comes
> from the LORD; we cannot **speak to you either bad or good**.

There is another instance in the story of Balaam:

> Num 24:13 - that even if Balak were to give me his house full of
> silver and gold, I could not do anything of my own accord, **good or
> bad**, to go beyond the command of the LORD? I will speak whatever the
> LORD says.

Even in the story of Jacob and Laban, Laban explains the meaning a few verses later:

> Gen 31:29 - It is in my power to do you harm. But the God of your
> father spoke to me last night, saying, ‘Be careful not to say anything
> to Jacob, **either good or bad**.’

Thus, Laban is essentially saying, as in all the other examples, that because they can neither speak good or bad, this is idiom for being unable to say anything - a perfect example of a merism or hendiadys.

Benson puts it this way:

> Genesis 31:24. Speak not to Jacob either good or bad — The Hebrew is,
> from good to bad — That is, enter into no altercations, and use no
> harsh language with him, which may occasion a quarrel. Say nothing
> against his going on with his journey, for the thing proceedeth from the Lord

The Pulpit commentary offers this:

> **either good or bad**. Literally, from good to bad, meaning that on meeting with Jacob he should not pass from peaceful greetings to
> bitter reproaches (Bush, Lunge), or say anything emphatic and decisive
> for the purpose of reversing what had occurred (Keil); or, perhaps
> more simply, say anything acrimonious or violent against Jacob
> (Rosenmüller, Murphy), the expression being a proverbial phrase for
> opposition or interference

Comment: Good as far as it goes, but you did not address the main question. (see my answer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very clear and informative.

Comment: @DanFefferman - that depends on whether one assumes that the OP already understood the meaning of the phrase and they were only wondering how it applied to Laban and Jacob. But since it's an ancient phrase without clear obvious meaning it seems possible that this is why it was difficult to understand what was meant. We can understand why God told Laban not to say anything inflammatory to Jacob, but why nothing good? Dottard's answer demonstrates that it was a common phrase which would have been understood to the hearer even if not to us, our difficulty compounded by a not so great translation.

Answer (score 5):

The reason God told Laban to say "neither good nor bad" to Jacob was that God had promised to protect Jacob:

Genesis 28:13

> I am with you and will protect you wherever you go, and bring you back
> to this land (Canaan). I will never leave you until I have done what I
> promised you.

@Dottard adequately explained the meaning to the term: God warned Laban not to engage Jacob with "fighting words." Laban nearly crossed the line when he spoke threateningly to Jacob: "It is in my power to do you harm." (Gen 31:29) Thankfully, because of God's warning, he went no further; and Jacob was able to proceed on his journey back to Canaan after concluding a covenant of peace with him. (31:44)

**Conclusion**:  God warned Laban to speak "neither good nor bad" to Jacob because Laban had the power to do Jacob harm. This was God's way of protecting Jacob in accordance with the promise of Genesis 28:13.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

The OP asks, "Is there a reason that God tells Laban to be careful to speak neither good nor bad?" As noted by @Dan Fefferman, God spoke to Laban in order to prevent him from harming Jacob. The focus of this response is on a different question: Why would that particular admonition work to deter Laban from going through with his plan to harm Jacob?

To answer this question, it is helpful to examine the larger context of Genesis 31. In the very first verse, the charge against Jacob and the reason for Laban’s ire against him is made clear. Despite the fact that it is Laban who has treated Jacob unfairly (Gen 19:18-26, 31:7), the words of Laban’s sons make it sound as though it is Laban who is the victim. That Laban views the situation in the same way (and may have himself been the source of these rumors/complaints) is evidenced in v2.

Genesis 31:1-2 NKJV

> <sup>**1**</sup> Now Jacob heard the words of Laban’s sons, saying, “Jacob has taken
> away all that was our father’s, and from what was our father’s he has
> acquired all this wealth.” <sup>**2**</sup> And Jacob saw the countenance of Laban,
> and indeed it was not favorable toward him as before.

In the instruction not to speak either good or bad, the idea is that Laban should not pronounce any judgment, for what seems good to man  may very well be deemed as evil in the eyes of God. This admonition speaks to the skill and tendency of men in general, and Laban in particular, to make arguments for their actions that on the surface appear to be good but in fact serve as a cover for evil. Recall that Laban had used a similar strategy when he tricked Jacob into marrying Leah (Gen 29:26).

God’s words to Laban in the dream deny Laban the chance of justifying his intention to harm Jacob. For in Laban’s mind, Jacob deserved to be punished. God’s words and the light they threw on Laban’s dark heart – his tendency to convince himself and others that he is only doing what is right – is the reason why they had such a powerful effect on him.

Comment: This is a good point. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be more of a "say nothing if you can't say anything good" type of phrase.
As in, bad words are merited but for contextually practical reasons to every unique scenario it is wiser to not say the bad words, therefore neither bad or good words are spoken.

Most of those examples were scenarios in which negativity is strongly felt.  So Good Words were already off the table, and that phrase emphasizes the point of being wit-ful/mindful.

The point of the phrasing is the social and self stanceed long-term modal-ling of relationships.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was God who rendered judgment to Laban to keep him from harming, Jacob.

God knew Labans heart and what he would have done to Jacob. He would've sent Jacob away, empty-handed, even after 20 years where he had served 14 years for his two daughters and six years for his flocks.  Labin had changed his wages 10 times..

> "If the God of my father, the God of Abraham and the Fear of Isaac, had not been with me, surely by now you would have sent me away empty-handed. But God has seen my affliction and the toil of my hands, and last night He rendered judgment.” Genesis 31:42"

God judged between the two of them.  God had blessed Laban for 20 years as Jacob served him with all his strength and even bore the loss of Laban's stolen beasts. Ge.31:32) He would've kept using Jacob, but it was time for him to go back home.  God kept  Laban from not only harming Jacob but his daughters as well.

> yakach ►3198 judgement
> Strong's Exhaustive Concordance
> appoint, argue, chasten, convince, correction, dispute, judge,
> A primitive root; to be right (i.e. Correct); reciprocal, to argue; causatively, to decide, justify or convict -- appoint, argue, chasten, convince, correct(-ion), daysman, dispute, judge, maintain, plead, reason (together), rebuke, reprove(-r), surely, in any wise.

The judgment is the same word used when God judged Abimelech who could have done a great sin against Sarah and Abraham.  God words were spoken to him was through a dream as well. Genesis 20:1-6

Afterwords Sara who trusted in God was vindicated as well.
To clear of accusation, blame, suspicion, or doubt with supporting arguments or proof.

> To Sarah he said, “Look, I have given your brother a thousand pieces of silver; it is your exoneration before all who are with you; you are completely vindicated.” Genesis 20:16

Both Abraham and Jacob were moved by fear and did what they did, and God  intervened in both of their lives, as well as the one who could've done both of them great harm. God did the judging between all of them and therefore kept the peace between them.